# Ember test fixtures belongsTo association

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, qunit

**EDIT:** If you are having issues with this, check your ember-data version. This issue is with v0.14 and there have been vast improvements since this release.

I am trying to test associations between the two Ember models below (using qUnit and Ember v1.0.0).

Models (Coffeescript):

```
App.Bud = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  building: DS.belongsTo('BuildingAI.Building')

App.Building = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  buds: DS.hasMany('BuildingAI.Bud')
```

Fixtures (Coffeescript):

```
App.Bud.FIXTURES = [
  id: 1
  name: 'foo_bud'
,
  id: 2
  name: 'bar_bud'
  circuits: [2]
]

App.Building.FIXTURES = [
  id: 1
  name: 'foo_building'
  buds: [1,2]
]
```

When trying to view the relationship in the console

```
App.Building.find(1).get('buds')
```

returns the expected result with the two 'buds'. However:

```
App.Bud.find(1).get('building')
```

returns null.

I've tried many different methods, including adding `building: 1` to the bud model (which crashes qunit) and adding `building_id: 1` which saves in the model but does not create a relationship.

How can I define the belongsTo relationship in the ember test fixture?

Comment: I currently use fixtures, defining both ways of my relationships with your "building: 1" syntax and it works like a charm [not using qUnit].

Comment: What version of Ember Data are you using? find hasn't been on the classes for quite a few versions

Comment: I've realized it's v0.14 of ember-data, which is now quite out of date. This is probably the cause of the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: this should help with the transition https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md